# Equivalencias del SETTING de Vb con C# (cambiar cadena de conexion)

Tags: c#

Sigo tratando de pasar mi codigo `vb` a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), con la ayuda de ustedes logre avanzar un poco, ahora me encuentro en esta situación:

`mCnxSifco` es la variable de mi setting que guarda mi cadena de conexion en el proyecto.

Este es mi codigo de `VB` que necesito pasar a `C#`:

```
this.Item("mCnxSifco") = acCnxApp.Trim.Replace("qmasuser", acUserId);
```

Cuando hago esto:

```
this.mCnxSifco =acCnxApp.Trim.Replace("qmasuser", acUserId);
```

Me marca error que solo es de lectura o que a la izquierda debe haber una variable, ya solo me falta reemplazar la nueva cadena que forme en la variable del setting.

Gracias

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos la declaracion de la variable `mCnxSifco`?

Comment: Buenas noches, estimado Einer, la variable la declaro en propiedades del proyecto, configuracion, NOMBRE: mCnxSifco, TIPO: (Cadena de Conexion), AMBITO: Aplicacion, VALOR: Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SIAF_TRANCIS_SRV;Integrated Security=True;Application Name=qmasuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) es un metodo y lo estas utilizando como campo/propiedad.

Intentalo de esta manera:

```
this.mCnxSifco =acCnxApp.Trim().Replace("qmasuser", acUserId);
```

Comment: Gracias de antemano Einer, pero me envia el mensaje que menciono anteriormente, No se puede asignar a la propiedad o el indicador "setting.mcnxSifco por que solo es de lectura.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes cambiar el valor de tu cadena de conexión cuando la has declarado en el settings:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var path = assembly.Location;

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApp1.Properties.Settings.CadenaConexion"]
            .ConnectionString = "Nueva cadena"; 
        config.Save();
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: No te ha servido este código para poder modificar la cadena de conexión introducida en el Settings ?